# Identify chip labelled SC1186E

Tags: integrated-circuit, adc, identification, energy, monitor

I am trying to identify the manufacturer and function of, and hopefully locate a data sheet for, this chip labelled SC1186E. It is in a three-phase power meter, so my guess is, that it is an ADC front end or a dedicated energy monitor IC manufactured in China. It is connected to / controlled by a Vango V9811A microcontroller. My web search has so far drawn a blank...

[image: SC1186E]

[image: Logo]

Update: Connecting a signal analyser to the eight lines linking the MCU and SC1186E boards suggested that some of the lines correspond to SPI communication. After reset there is a fairly long data exchange, probably setup and calibration. Then finally there appears to be a loop repeated every 1s, where each time 3x3x4 bytes are transferred:

[image: traces]

The data transferred is:

```
0000  90  e9  44  42
0004  92  a3  14  b6
0008  94  00  02  69
000c  90  e9  45  41
0010  92  15  84  d4
0014  94  01  07  63
0018  90  e9  46  40
001c  92  cc  14  8d
0020  94  00  02  69
```

The '90e94442', '90e94541', '90e94640' values repeat without change, the other values vary depending on the voltage / current seen by the meter - these are probably register read SPI commands.

Unfortunately, this data format does not even remotely match any of the formats used by mainstream energy meter chip manufacturers, e.g Cirrus, AD, TI, ST, Maxim, Belling, etc.

Comment: BTW, it is not the Semtech SC1186CSW 'Programmable Synchronous DC/DC Converter, Dual Low Dropout Regulator Controller'.

Comment: Zoom in on the IC more closely, and more "flat" (not at an angle).    Take a good picture of the logo.  Crop it.  Use Google to reverse-image search, and maybe you'll discover the manufacturer.

Comment: @KB Thanks for the suggestion - tried, but no joy. After zooming in I do wonder though whether logo is '5G' instead of 'SG'.

Comment: Just the S/5 letter looks like Signetics. Some joint venture between them and some other company starting with G before folding into Philips?

Answer (score 1):

I’m pretty sure the manufacturer is [Beijing Smart Chip](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%8C%97%E4%BA%AC%E6%99%BA%E8%8A%AF%E5%BE%AE%E7%94%B5%E5%AD%90%E7%A7%91%E6%8A%80%E6%9C%89%E9%99%90%E5%85%AC%E5%8F%B8/19980688?fr=aladdin) (aka Nari Smart Chip aka Beijing Zhixin Microelectronics Technology aka Zhixin Company). Their logo looks very similar to the logo on the chip, maybe the one on the chip is an older logo:

[image]

(Source: [riscv.org](https://riscv.org/member/beijing-smartchip-microelectronics-technology-co-ltd/))

They seem to be a [pretty big company](https://www.eenewseurope.com/en/who-are-chinas-biggest-fabless-chipmakers/) in China, yet I couldn't find any homepage or online presence. So I can only go by clues:

- The "SC" in SC1186E could stand for "Smart Chip"
- [This website](https://www.dzsc.com/S/SC1186E.html) sells a 44pin SC1186E IC. It lists the manufacturer as "智芯微" which means "Zhixin" and is part of Chinese name of the company "Beijing Zhixin Microelectronics Technology Co"
- This [Chinese article](https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1749098419835244508&wfr=spider&for=pc) mentions that the SC1186E is used as power meter on a SCMB9005 board that is manufactured by Zhixin Microelectronics.

Since this company has no online presence (as far as I can tell), I highly doubt there is any public information available on this chip.